# Weird exception when opening a database in PhpStorm?

Tags: database, sqlite, phpstorm

I downloaded a database from a github source called mhgdb.db. I've never heard of a ".db" extension so I renamed it to mhgdb.txt and opened that up and the first thing I see is this: 
[image]

So that made me think it was using sqlite3. I renamed it back to mhgdb.db and I'm trying to add it as the data source for my PhpStorm project, but I'm getting an error/exception when I try and test the connection. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you are receiving you need to add the sqlite driver class to your configuration in the 'Drivers' list. You can download the .jar here https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/releases